# RC-LC network equals lowpass filter of third order?

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, passive-networks

As far as I know only this are two lowpass filters (R-C1, L-C2) of order 1 and 2 respectively. Is it possible to denote this circuit as Low-pass filter of third order? Or is it possible to transform this circuit into a standard RLC-filter form?

[image: RC-LC Network]

Comment: Yes, of course. It is one of the passive lowpass structures of 3rd order. It is, for example, used as feedback path in the Colpitt oscillator

Comment: It cannot be generally transformed back to an RLC filter unless C1 is removed.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to denote this circuit as Low-pass filter of third order?

Yes. It has three reactive components, and no two of those components are in pure series or parallel configuration.

> is it possible to transform this circuit into a standard RLC-filter form?

At a single frequency, this circuit can be transformed. However, as a *filter*, i.e. a circuit that reacts differently to different frequencies, it is not equivalent to a 2nd order RLC filter.

A 2nd order filter has an asymptotic roll-off of -40 dB / decade. A 3rd order filter, such as this, has an asymptotic roll-off of -60 dB / decade.

Answer (score 3):

Transfer function of your circuit is:

$$H(s)=\frac{Vo}{V1}=\frac{1}{RLC_1C_2s^3+LC_2s^2+R(C_1+C_2)s+1}$$

that is obviously order 3 in denominator.

At frequence w=0, |H|=1. At frequence infinite, |H|=0. Thus, it is low pass.

To convert it in a second order filter, term in s^3 must be equal to zero and keep second order one:

$$RLC_1C_2=0$$
$$LC_2 \ne 0 $$

that is only possible removing R or C_1 (or both) from the circuit. Remove R converts it to an usual LC filter (with a waste of current across C_1) and remove C_1 converts it to a classical RLC.

Answer (score 2):

This is to expand on the [earlier answer by @pasabaporaqui](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/581439/262544).  I'm learning to do circuit analysis in s-domain.  I got the same transfer function as @pasabaporaqui.  I might as well post my steps here.

blue arrows are my arbitrary choices for positive current directions

[image: 3rd order LCR circuit]

Kirchhoff's current law (KCL) for nets \$ V_2 \$ and \$ V_o \$

\$ \left\{  \begin{array} {l}
\cfrac {V_2 - V_1} {R} + s C_1 V_2- \cfrac {V_o - V_2} {sL} = 0 \\
\cfrac {V_o - V_2} {sL} + s C_2 V_o = 0
\end{array} \right . \$

Collecting terms and factoring out voltages, I get

\$ \left\{  \begin{array} {l}
V_2 \left(\cfrac {1} {R} + s C_1 + \cfrac {1} {sL} \right) = \cfrac {V_o} {sL} + \cfrac {V_1} {R} \\ 
\cfrac {V_2} {sL} = V_o \left( \cfrac {1} {sL} + s C_2 \right)
\end{array} \right . \$

\$ \left\{  \begin{array} {l}
V_2 \left( s^2 L C_1 R + sL +R \right) = V_o R + s L V_1 \\ 
V_o \left( s^2 L C_2 + 1 \right) = V_2
\end{array} \right . \$

Substituting expression for \$ V_2 \$ into the second equation, I get

\$ V_o \left( s^2 L C_2 + 1 \right) \left( s^2L C_1 R + sL + R \right)  = V_o R + s L V_1 \$

\$ \cfrac {V_o}{V_1} = \cfrac{1}{s^3 L C_1 C_2 R + s^2 L C_2 + s (C_1+C_2)R+1} \$

Answer (score -3):

You can change it back to RLC filter by removing the C1 however you lose two things :
first you back to the first order filter and second there is a change at the Cut off frequency

Comment: After removing C1, the remaining lowpass is, of course, second order !